# Navigate ul list items on KeyUP

Tags: javascript, html

I created a menu using ul li. I want to allow the user to navigate in this menu using arrow down and up onKeyUP. Is there any way to do this without using jquery ?
I tried this but it didn't work for me :

```js
 function scrollList() {
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  const first = list.firstChild;
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  if (document.activeElement === input) {
    input.blur();
    first.focus();
    first.style.fontSize = 'large';
  } else {
    document.activeElement.nextSibling.focus();
  }
}

// I called this function like this: 

if (e.which == 40) {
  scrollList();
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id='li'>Item 1</li>
  <li id='li'>Item 2</li>
  <li id='li'>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that when i put the focus on anther element, document.activeElement returns body.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Vtn5Y/

Comment: @Teuta Koraqi In fact i want to do something like that but without using jquery

Comment: But, what do you want to use instead JQuery?

Comment: @Teuta Koraqi I have to use only JavaScript

Comment: Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/evBkC/8/

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Thanks a lot, this resolves my problem :)

Comment: Glad to help you! :)